# lua Import .BVH motion data/ LUA table then animate .OBJ using table

Tags: lua

× 1126

Is this possible i since .BVH files are text driven and .OBJ files are tet driven too, i have been studying this code but i seem to be missing something.

```
 import script to lua table


--[[ Parses a .bvh (motion capture) file into Lua table format.

--]]

-- A list of valid BVH transform tokens and their -- quaternion sequence equivalents. local xform_tokens = {

}

Xrotation = "rx", Yrotation = "ry", Zrotation = "rz", Xposition = "tx", Yposition = "ty", Zposition = "tz"

-- Main Function

BVH2Table = function(bhvfilename) local bhvfile, linenumber, bvhtable, levels_temp_info, line, rest, _ =

0)

assert(io.open(bhvfilename)), 0, {}, {}

local function readline() repeat

linenumber = linenumber + 1 line = bhvfile:read("*line") -- trim line = line and string.gsub(string.gsub(line,"^[ \t]*", ""), "[ \t\n]*$", "") or nil -- enable comments and while lines

until not line or (line ~= "" and string.sub(line, 1, 1) ~= "#") _,_,token = string.find(line or "","^([%u%l{}:]+)") -- rest of line, stripped _,_,rest = string.find(line or "", "^[%u%l{}:]+[ \t]([%a%d%s%c%p]*)")

end local function parse_error(err, ...)

error(string.format("%s:%d: %s", bhvfilename, linenumber, string.format(err, unpack(arg))),

end

local function checktoken(ctoken) if ctoken ~= token then

parse_error("token %s expected, got %s", ctoken, token) bvhtable.root_segment = {}

end

end

local function read_joint_level(level) local level_temp_info = { rotation_seq = {}, level = level } -- stored info for use at animation frame decoding time table.insert(levels_temp_info, level_temp_info) level.rotation = {} -- one for each animation frame



checktoken("{") readline() while token ~= "}" do

if token == "OFFSET" then local ox, oy, oz

_, _, ox, oy, oz = string.find(rest, "[ \t]*([%-%+%d%.]+)[ \t]+([%-%+%d%.]+)[ \t]+([%-%+%d%.]+)")

angle

end

table.insert(level_temp_info.rotation_seq, token) table.insert(level_temp_info.rotation_seq, 0)

-- "rx", "ry", or "rz" -- spot to put the

end

level.offset = vec4(ox, oy, oz) elseif token == "CHANNELS" then

local _, e, channelcount = string.find(rest, "([%d]+)[ \t]*") for i=1, channelcount do

local chname -- extract channel name (such as "Xrotation") _, e, chname = string.find(rest, "([%w]+)[ \t]*", e)local token = xform_tokens[chname] or

parse_error("unknown channel type %s", chname or "(nil)") if string.sub(token, 1,1) ~= "t" then -- ignore translation tokens.

end

end elseif token == "JOINT" or token == "End" then

local newlevel = {} level.segments = level.segments or {} -- make sure we have a table therelevel.segments[(token == "End") and "EndSite" or rest] = newlevel -- new level readline() read_joint_level(newlevel)

elseif token ~= "}" then

parse_error("illegal/unknown token '%s'", token) readline()

end

-- Read hierarchy

readline() checktoken("HIERARCHY") readline() checktoken("ROOT") readline() read_joint_level(bvhtable.root_segment) readline()

-- Read frames (insert them into the right places of the hierarchy)

checktoken("MOTION") readline()

checktoken("Frames:") _,_,bvhtable.framecount = string.find(rest, "([%d]+)") readline()

checktoken("Frame") _,_,bvhtable.frametime = string.find(rest, "([%d%.]+)") readline()

for fr = 1, bvhtable.framecount do if token or not line then parse_error("frame data expected") end local e = 1

-- Skip global translation - we don't need it

for l = 1, 3 do local n

end

_,e,n = string.find(line, "([%-%+%d%.]+)[\t ]*", e)

-- fill in the rotation sequence in rotation_seq with -- the right angles, turn it into a quaternion for l = 1,table.getn(levels_temp_info) do

local rs = levels_temp_info[l].rotation_seq for c = 2, table.getn(rs), 2 do

end return bvhtable

end

end

local n _,e,n = string.find(line, "([%-%+%d%.]+)[\t ]*", e) -- capture number rs[c] = math.rad(tonumber(n)) -- insert right number into rotation sequence

-- constructs quad from rotation sequence

levels_temp_info[l].level.rotation[fr] = quat(unpack(rs)) readline()



end
```

a BVH example------------------------

```
HIERARCHY

ROOT hip

{

OFFSET 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 

CHANNELS 6 Xposition Yposition Zposition Xrotation Zrotation Yrotation

JOINT abdomen

{

OFFSET 0.000000 3.402643 0.000000 

CHANNELS 3 Xrotation Zrotation Yrotation

JOINT chest

{

OFFSET 0.000000 8.438565 -0.680529 

CHANNELS 3 Xrotation Zrotation Yrotation

JOINT neck

{

OFFSET 0.000000 10.207942 -0.272212 

CHANNELS 3 Xrotation Zrotation Yrotation

JOINT head

{

OFFSET 0.000000 3.130431 0.000000 

CHANNELS 3 Xrotation Zrotation Yrotation

End Site

{

OFFSET 0.000000 3.130435 0.000000 

}

}

}

JOINT lCollar

{

OFFSET 3.470700 6.669187 -0.816635 

CHANNELS 3 Yrotation Zrotation Xrotation

JOINT lShldr

{

OFFSET 3.198488 0.000000 0.000000 

CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Yrotation Xrotation

JOINT lForeArm

{

OFFSET 10.139888 0.000000 0.000000 

CHANNELS 3 Yrotation Zrotation Xrotation

JOINT lHand

{

OFFSET 8.370511 0.000000 0.000000 

CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Yrotation Xrotation

End Site

{

OFFSET 4.083176 0.000000 0.000000 

}

}

}

}

}

JOINT rCollar

{

OFFSET -3.470700 6.669187 -0.816635 

CHANNELS 3 Yrotation Zrotation Xrotation

JOINT rShldr

{

OFFSET -3.198488 0.000000 0.000000 

CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Yrotation Xrotation

JOINT rForeArm

{

OFFSET -10.139888 0.000000 0.000000 

CHANNELS 3 Yrotation Zrotation Xrotation

JOINT rHand

{

OFFSET -8.370511 0.000000 0.000000 

CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Yrotation Xrotation

End Site

{

OFFSET -4.083176 0.000000 0.000000 

}

}

}

}

}

}

}

JOINT lThigh

{

OFFSET 5.308129 -1.633274 1.361059 

CHANNELS 3 Xrotation Zrotation Yrotation

JOINT lShin

{

OFFSET -2.041588 -20.007561 0.000000 

CHANNELS 3 Xrotation Zrotation Yrotation

JOINT lFoot

{

OFFSET 0.000000 -19.190928 -1.224953 

CHANNELS 3 Xrotation Yrotation Zrotation

End Site

{

OFFSET 0.000000 -2.449906 4.627600 

}

}

}

}

JOINT rThigh

{

OFFSET -5.308129 -1.633274 1.361059 

CHANNELS 3 Xrotation Zrotation Yrotation

JOINT rShin

{

OFFSET 2.041588 -20.007561 0.000000 

CHANNELS 3 Xrotation Zrotation Yrotation

JOINT rFoot

{

OFFSET 0.000000 -19.190928 -1.224953 

CHANNELS 3 Xrotation Yrotation Zrotation

End Site

{

OFFSET 0.000000 -2.449906 4.627600 

}

}

}

}

}

MOTION

Frames: 3

Frame Time: 0.033333

0.334508 49.638664 0.334508 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 38.066406 -0.007741 -0.006054 -23.085936 -0.009696 0.000434 30.252640 10.959431 -20.480103 10.524219 0.508720 -0.030344 -26.006567 -12.095985 -14.674844 -69.630486 -2.351615 4.234642 -48.221165 -2.682419 1.985076 -59.212875 -62.296707 83.528305 -26.749914 11.561311 -14.691852 55.618294 -19.902231 31.929420 90.271812 3.187478 0.956403 39.090054 47.092247 65.247185 2.376307 2.553305 0.602678 2.310530 -1.853541 -1.517510 -4.662024 0.846682 -0.614829 2.206921 -3.085746 -0.644749 2.650610 1.831281 1.545582 -4.841407 -0.873909 1.111763 

0.334508 49.638664 0.334508 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 38.066406 -0.007741 -0.006054 -22.246092 -0.009701 0.000292 34.186817 10.756927 -18.382940 10.524219 0.508720 -0.030344 -23.362236 -12.731888 -10.985835 -69.819717 -18.002703 5.484021 -48.221165 -2.682419 1.985076 -59.212875 -62.296707 83.528305 -25.608553 10.831628 -11.038041 64.898254 -5.748130 27.512720 84.760063 3.170111 1.120247 39.090054 47.092247 65.247185 2.376307 2.553305 0.602678 2.310530 -1.853541 -1.517510 -4.662024 0.846682 -0.614829 2.206921 -3.085746 -0.644749 2.650610 1.831281 1.545582 -4.841407 -0.873909 1.111763 

0.334508 49.638664 0.334508 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 38.066406 -0.007741 -0.006054 -22.246092 -0.009701 0.000292 37.417660 9.695412 -15.840567 10.524219 0.508720 -0.030344 -20.065645 -13.200043 -8.106980 -66.682304 -8.166236 6.721763 -48.221165 -2.682419 1.985076 -59.212875 -62.296707 83.528305 -23.474226 10.225674 -8.213222 75.448418 13.496569 25.332378 71.978508 3.057956 1.458179 39.090054 47.092247 65.247185 2.376307 2.553305 0.602678 2.310530 -1.853541 -1.517510 -4.662024 0.846682 -0.614829 2.206921 -3.085746 -0.644749 2.650610 1.831281 1.545582 -4.841407 -0.873909 1.111763
```

The big issue is how would i assign this data in an .OBJ file from the table?

Comment: welcome to SO.  In the future, make sure to use the code tool to make your code more readable (I've already submitted an edit to the mods).  Also, reduce your code to the minimum needed to recreate a problem.

Comment: Just pointing those interested to the origin of the code (and study): **Real-time full-body motion capture in Virtual Worlds** Final Project by Daan Nusman [document PDF](http://essay.utwente.nl/57579/1/scriptie_Nusman.pdf) Sam

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but your question seems to how do I apply an 3d animation file to a 3d model file.

The answer is you don't, they are both just file formats and you are probably asking the wrong question.

Answer (score 0):

.obj does not support animation, so you can't put the animation data into the .obj file.

Now if you were using Lua as the scripting language for a 3D engine you could load the .bvh and then apply those movements to the .obj model loaded in the 3D engine, but then that's a question more about your 3D engine than about Lua.